# Highcharts not working on webpage

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Hopefully somebody can help me with this because it has been bugging me for days.

I am building a website that uses the Highcharts library to display a single line series chart. For some reason I cannot get the demo chart to display on my page. I have put my CSS, javascript and html into a jsFiddle and it displays correctly but when I open the page normally in HTML everything loads except for the chart.

```
here is the jsFiddle of my webpage:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s5RUX/

```
here is the jsFiddle of the demo on the highcharts website:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z55AA/

Can anybody tell me what is going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You propably have to insert the scripts in a specific order (jQuery library first, then third-party one). If it's not this, check if functions are not colliding with each others by debugger (built-in in chrome, for example), or is the proper jQuery version in your site is installed.

Comment: I insert jquery.js before the highcharts.js and highstocks.js and I am using version 1.8.3 of jQuery which is listed on the highcharts website as a compatible version. The console isnt giving me much clues.                                                          Uncaught Highcharts error #16: www.highcharts.com/errors/16 highstock.js:16
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You pated the code a-is in your website? Because it seems that you inserted the script's code into your `<body>` section, am I right? If so, please try to insert it in the `<head>` - it works for me as HTML.

Comment: Yeah I have pasted the code exactly like how it is in my website. I have moved the script parts into the head section and it still doesnt work. I dont understand why.

Comment: aha sorted it, it was an error in the call to the highcharts.js function. Thank you for the help fixing it :)

Comment: @James: can you share your specific answer? I'm suing http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/intraday-area/ as code to copy int my index.jsp, where I have a ton of ther java sciprt that build other highcharts. I have a suspicion is has something do do with the call back function(data) but not sure what to change it to exactly?

Comment: Newer versions of highcharts can be called using the highcharts() function.  It seems older versions of Highcharts need to use "new Highcharts.Chart(settings)"

Answer (score 3):

Highstock includes Highcharts, so eliminate the Highcharts reference in your scrip loads and this error should go away.